# AWS SNS opt-out reply does not stop messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am testing the AWS SNS services available, and my understanding is that a subscribed number to a topic should be able to opt-out of future messages by replying with "STOP" as seen in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_manage.html.

However, I cannot actually opt-out.  Here are the steps I'm taking to test the functionality:

1. Subscribe to the topic.
2. Publish a message to the topic.
3. Receive message.
4. Reply to the message with "STOP".
5. Confirm that I get a new message confirming the opt-out which says I will not receive further messages.
6. Publish a new message to the topic.
7. Receive message unexpectedly.

I also do not see my any phone numbers in the "Opted-out phone numbers" console screen.

What am I missing?